# Control the size of points in an R scatterplot?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

In R, the `plot()` function takes a `pch` argument that controls the appearance of the points in the plot.  I'm making scatterplots with tens of thousands of points and prefer a small, but not too small dot.  Basically, I find `pch='.'` to be too small, but `pch=19` to be too fat.  Is there something in the middle or some way to scale the dots down somehow?

Comment: Rather than making dots smaller, is there a way to just plot say 100 random data points would would be easier to see than 1000?

Comment: For many small points, using alpha (transparency) can make a scatter plot much more informative than just using fewer points to plot it.

Comment: I suggest not to use `pch='.'`, it will be off center.  Source: I used to use `pch='.'` often

Comment: @geneorama Do you mean using `·` instead of `.`?

Comment: @nanaki more or less, but oddly your symbol shows up as tiny boxes when I use it in R. The answers below do a good job at explaining the right approach.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try the `cex` argument:

`?par`

- `cex`
  A numerical value giving the
  amount by which plotting text and
  symbols should be magnified relative
  to the default. Note that some
  graphics functions such as
  plot.default have an argument of this
  name which multiplies this graphical
  parameter, and some functions such as
  points accept a vector of values
  which are recycled. Other uses will
  take just the first value if a vector
  of length greater than one is
  supplied.

Comment: i don't think i would ever use 'cex' to control symbol size unless i had no other option. It only works some of the time; the rule is that when 'cex' is set via 'par', it affects the size of (most) text on the plot, when set inside 'plot', 'cex' affects only symbol size. So if you mis-apply that rule then not only is your symbol size not changed, but you now have multiple parameters affecting text size (cex.axis, cex.lab, cex.main, and cex.sub--all do the same job as 'cex', only piece-wise). Code like that is difficult to maintain and extend.

Comment: Agree.  Setting `cex` globally via `par` changes all kinds of things, including figure margins, that you have to correct for.  setting `cex` within `plot`, however, seems to work.

Comment: The advice espoused above by doug's comment is not necessarily _wrong_ but it does significantly overstate any potential problems with using the `cex` argument when plotting. There are many, many instances where it is both useful and the best option.

Comment: `lwd` controls the line width of the pch, e.g. `plot(1:5, pch=1:5, col=1:5, lwd=1:5)`.  Thank you to  http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-plot-pch-symbols-the-different-point-shapes-available-in-r

Answer (score 99):

**pch=20** returns a symbol sized *between* "." and 19.

It's a *filled* symbol (which is probably what you want).

Aside from that, even the base graphics system in R allows a user fine-grained control over symbol size, color, and shape. E.g.,

```
dfx = data.frame(ev1=1:10, ev2=sample(10:99, 10), ev3=10:1)

with(dfx, symbols(x=ev1, y=ev2, circles=ev3, inches=1/3,
                  ann=F, bg="steelblue2", fg=NULL))
```

[image: Graph example]

Comment: I love this plot, but I would like the radius to be equal to the number of observations on that point, could you show me how to do that?

Comment: `pi*R^2` (the surface) should be proportional to the number of observations.

Comment: @saratis This will do what you want: `symbols(x=dfx$ev1, y=dfx$ev2, circles=sqrt(dfx$ev3/pi), inches=1/3, ann=F, bg="steelblue2", fg=NULL)`

Comment: any idea on how I could use this to plot multiple series on the same graph? i.e. "points(x=dfx2$ev1, y=dfx2$ev2, circles = dfx2$ev3, ... )" does not work.

Comment: In case you're wondering "What is an inch?" [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034898/what-is-an-inch-setting-the-length-for-arrows)

Answer (score 29):

As ***rcs*** stated, `cex` will do the job in base graphics package. I reckon that you're not willing to do your graph in `ggplot2` but if you do, there's a `size` aesthetic attribute, that you can easily control (`ggplot2` has user-friendly function arguments: instead of typing `cex` (character expansion), in `ggplot2` you can type e.g. `size = 2` and you'll get 2mm point).

Here's the example:

```
### base graphics ###
plot(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, pch = 16, cex = .9)

### ggplot2 ###
# with qplot()
qplot(mpg, hp, data = mtcars, size = I(2))
# or with ggplot() + geom_point()
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp), size = 2) + geom_point()
# or another solution:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point(size = 2)
```

Comment: And, if you're really plotting tens of thousands of points, ggplot2 has several alternative ways to make that look nice - alpha adjustments, hex bins, contour plots, etc.  Check out pages 72-77 of the ggplot2 book, if there's one in your library or if your library has electronic access to Springer books (I think most of the R books are in there).

Comment: Yup... I especially use `alpha` in scatterplots, to avoid overplotting.

Comment: @aL3xa You can use _alpha_ in base graphics package. Just add for example `col = rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6)` in plot options.