# R plot - make a big circle at a point

Tags: r, plot

How can I make a point that is a big, NOT colored in circle?

x0 and y0 are just lists with 1 value.

So this just plots one value:

```
points(x=x0,y=y0,col="green",pch=16)
```

But the circle is sort of small, and it's colored in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control the size of points in an R scatterplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579995/control-the-size-of-points-in-an-r-scatterplot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the single plotting character larger, use `cex`, as in:

```
points(x = x0, y = y0, col = "green", pch = 16, cex = 10)
```

Please read (even though it's kind of tedious) `?par` for base graphics options.

**EDIT**

I suppose I should add (even though I agree this question is mostly a duplicate) that the second part of your question simply requires a different value for `pch`. Sounds like `pch = 1` is what you want, but you can see lots of options via `example("points")`.

Answer (score 6):

Depending how big you the circles you want, you could also consider the `symbols()` function.

```
## from ?symbols
N <- nrow(trees)
with(trees, {
## Girth is diameter in inches
symbols(Height, Volume, circles = Girth/24, inches = FALSE,
        main = "Trees' Girth") # xlab and ylab automatically
})
```

[image: plot showing use of symbols()]

Answer (score 3):

The package shape contains a collection of functions for plotting all kind of graphical shapes ( see vignette("shape") ). In your case:

```
install.packages("shape")
require("shape")
emptyplot(c(0, 1))
plotcircle(mid = c(0.5, 0.5), r = 0.25)
```

[image]