# R - Boxplot with median values temperature coloured

Tags: r, colors, boxplot

I have a boxplot for 39 species and the annual temperature values of their distribution range (`bio01`). The median values are in row 3 of the `boxplot$stats`. I want to color the highest median value red and the lowest blue, i.e. a temperature gradient. The code below for `medcol` is not working. Can somebody suggest a solution?

```
b <- boxplot(bio01 ~ species, data=species.threshold.22.climate.751, las=2, ylab ="bio01", par(mar = c(18, 5,5, 2)+ 0.1), cex.names=0.2, bw = 5, medcol=b$stat[3,])
b$stats
```

Answer (score 3):

This should see you on the right track:

```
# Dummy data
x = data.frame(col1=rep(month.abb, 20), col2=rnorm(20*12))

# develop colour gradient
cols = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))
# Calculate medians
m = unname(tapply(x$col2, x$col1, median))

# Plot and colour by size of median
boxplot(col2 ~ col1, x, col=cols(length(unique(x$col1)))[findInterval(m, sort(m))])
```

And the output:
[image]

With thanks to [One colour gradient according to value in column scatterplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827214/one-colour-gradient-according-to-value-in-column-scatterplot-in-r) for the interval help.

Comment: Great, glad to help @niels-raes. Can you mark my answer as correct please?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass `b$stats[,3]` to `boxplot`, which itself creates the variable `b`. This won't work.

The simplest thing is maybe to call boxplot twice. Here's an example that works:

```
b <- boxplot(weight ~ Diet, data=ChickWeight)
boxplot(weight ~ Diet, data=ChickWeight, medcol=order(b$stats[,3]))
```

or you can do something more complex like

```
b <- boxplot(weight ~ Diet, data=ChickWeight)
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))
colors <- colors(nrow(b$stats))
boxplot(weight ~ Diet, data=ChickWeight, medcol=colors[order(b$stats[,3])])
```