# What is an inch? Setting the length for arrows

Tags: r, plot

Somewhat inexplicably, the `length` parameter in `arrows` is specified in inches (from `?arrows`):

> `length`  length of the edges of the arrow head (in inches).

[R source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5521298bbb67ac19ce15f751c1cab5f5a67f411f/src/library/graphics/src/graphics.c#L3051) even goes so far as to explicitly make note that this measurement is in inches in a comment, highlighting how peculiar this design is.

That means  the relative size of the arrows depends on `dev.size()`. What's not clear is how to translate inches into axis units (which are infinitely more useful in the first place). Here's a simplified version:

```
h = c(1, 2, 3)
xs = barplot(h, space = 0, ylim = c(0, 4))
arrows(xs, h - .5, xs, h + .5,
       length = .5*mean(diff(xs)))
```

How this displays will depend on the device. E.g. here is the output on this device:

```
png('test.png', width = 5, height = 5)
```

[image: A barplot with three bars with heights increasing from left to right; each has an upward-pointing arrow starting within the bar and extending above it.]

And here it is on another:

```
png('test.png', width = 8, height = 8)
```

[image: The same plot, but scaled larger; the arrows look relatively smaller on this version despite the same code (besides the call to png()) underlying it.]

It's a bit of an optical illusion to tell on sight, but the arrows are indeed the same width in the two plots. How can I control this so that both plots (which convey the same data) display identically? More specifically, how can I make sure that the arrows are *exactly* .5 **plot units** in width?

Comment: Maybe use arrow character? `text(seq(0.5, 3, 1), h, "↑", cex = 5)`

Comment: @zx8754 thanks. Actually I'm using `code = 3L` as well (these will be standard error bars _a la_ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22037078/3576984))

Comment: Internally, there's a [`Convert` function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5521298bbb67ac19ce15f751c1cab5f5a67f411f/src/library/graphics/src/graphics.c#L93-L95), not clear if any user-facing version of that exists

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I spent far too much time in the rabbit hole on this, but here goes. I'll document a bit of my journey first to aid others who happen upon this in the types of nooks and crannies to search when trying to pull yourself up by your bootstraps.

I started looking in the source of `arrows`, but to no avail, since it quickly dives into internal code. So I searched the [R source](https://github.com/wch/r-source) for `"C_arrows"` to find what's happening; luckily, it's [not *too* esoteric](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/graphics/src/plot.c#L1888), as far as R internal code goes. Poking around it seems the workhorse is actually [`GArrow`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5521298bbb67ac19ce15f751c1cab5f5a67f411f/src/library/graphics/src/graphics.c#L3052), but this was a dead end, as it seems the `length` parameter isn't really transformed there (IIUC this means the conversion to inches is done for the other coordinates and `length` is untouched). But I happened to notice some `GConvert` calls that looked closer to what I want and hoped to find some user-facing function that appeals to these directly.

This led me to go back to R and to simply run through the gamut of functions in the same package as `arrows` looking for anything that could be useful:

```
ls(envir = as.environment('package:grDevices'))
ls(envir = as.environment('package:graphics'))
```

Finally I found three functions in `graphics`: `xinch`, `yinch`, and `xyinch` (all found on `?xinch`) are used for the *opposite* of my goal here -- namely, they take *inches* and convert them into *device units* (in the x, y, and x&y directions, respectively). Luckily enough, these functions are all very simple, e.g. the work horse of `xinch` is the conversion factor:

```
diff(par("usr")[1:2])/par("pin")[1L]
```

Examining `?par` (for the 1,000,000th time), indeed `pin` and `usr` are exactly the graphical parameter we need (`pin` is new to me, `usr` comes up here and there):

> `pin` The current plot dimensions, (width, height), in inches.
>
> `usr` A vector of the form `c(x1, x2, y1, y2)` giving the extremes of the user coordinates of the plotting region.

Hence, we can convert from *plot units* to *inches* by inverting this function:

```
xinch_inv = function(dev_unit) {
    dev_unit * par("pin")[1L]/diff(par("usr")[1:2])
}

h = c(1, 2, 3)
xs = barplot(h, space = 0, ylim = c(0, 4))
arrows(xs, h - .5, xs, h + .5,
       # just convert plot units to inches
       length = xinch_inv(.5*mean(diff(xs))))
```

Resulting in (5x5):

[image]

And (8x8):

[image]

One further note, it appears `length` is the length of *each side* of the arrow head -- using `length = xinch_inv(.5), code = 3, angle = 90` results in segments as wide as the bars (i.e., 1).

On the off chance you're interested, I've packaged these in my [package](https://github.com/MichaelChirico/funchir) as `xdev2in`, etc.; GitHub only for now.