# Change size of points in R using plot() with multiple added points()

Tags: r, plot, plotrix, rescale

The data is available [here](https://figshare.com/s/47bd7da8f18d954452b6).

I am trying to generate the below plot (proportion of individuals~year), with the exception that I need to scale all the points (`resF`, `resM`, `immF`, and `immM`) to the number of observations for each column (`resFN`, `resMN`, `immFN`, and `immMN`). 
[image]

The code I use to make the above plot is below:

```
library (plotrix)

plot(resF~year,data=data, type="b", col="black", xlab="Settlement year", ylab="Number of individuals", bty="l", pch=17, ylim=c(0,1))
ablineclip(v=1993, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
ablineclip(v=1998, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
ablineclip(v=2005, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
ablineclip(v=2010, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
ablineclip(v=2014, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
points(resF~year,data=data, col="black", type="b", pch=17)
points(resM~year,data=data, col="grey", type="b", pch=16)
points(immF~year,data=data, col="red", type="b", pch=17)
points(immM~year,data=data, col="orange", type="b", pch=16)
legend("topright", c("Resident females","Resident males", "Immigrant females", "Immigrant males"), col=c("black", "grey","red", "orange"), pch=c(17, 16, 17, 16), box.lty=0)
```

I am plotting the `resF`, and adding points for `resM`, `immF`, and `immM`. I want to scale the points according to the number of observations for each column. For example, `resF` would need to be rescaled according to the number of observations in column `resFN`, `resM` scaled to number in `resMN`, etc.

Based on what I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579995/control-the-size-of-points-in-an-r-scatterplot), I should be able to rescale the points by adding `symbols(x=data$resFN, y=data$year, circles=sqrt(data$resFN/pi), inches=1/3, ann=F, bg="steelblue2", fg=NULL)` to my `plot()` code. I am encountering problems since I am adding multiple `points()` to the original `plot()` and I am also rescaling according to values in different columns.

Any suggestions for how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You probably want the `cex` argument in each `points()` call, but you'll need to prep the scaled number of observations for each group in advance.

Comment: (I really think the advice in that linked question is bad, or at least misleading.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, I wouldn't necessarily recommend this particular scaling, but this gives you basic idea. I would just scale the points however you deem appropriate. In particular, you need to decide if they should be scaled separately by category, or scaled by the same amount across all categories.

```
plot(resF~year,data=data, type="b", col="black", xlab="Settlement year", 
     ylab="Number of individuals", bty="l", pch=17, ylim=c(0,1))
ablineclip(v=1993, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
ablineclip(v=1998, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
ablineclip(v=2005, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
ablineclip(v=2010, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
ablineclip(v=2014, col="grey95", lwd=14, y1=0)
points(resF~year,data=data, col="black", type="b", pch=17,cex = resFN / median(resFN))
points(resM~year,data=data, col="grey", type="b", pch=16,cex = resMN / median(resMN))
points(immF~year,data=data, col="red", type="b", pch=17,cex = immFN / median(immFN))
points(immM~year,data=data, col="orange", type="b", pch=16,cex = immMN / median(immMN))
legend("topright", c("Resident females","Resident males", "Immigrant females", "Immigrant males"), 
       col=c("black", "grey","red", "orange"), pch=c(17, 16, 17, 16), box.lty=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to make sure they are scaled by the same amount across all categories.

Comment: How would I modify the `cex=` script to make it so that they are scaled by the same amount across all categories?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist Instead of dividing by the median of each column, figure out the median of all four columns and divide by that.