# how can i make the circles of my plot smaller in R?

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, k-means, scatter-plot

This is the code I used:

```
resources <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/resources.csv")

res <- subset(resources, select = c("cty_name", "year", "regime",
                             "oil", "logGDPcp", "illit"))
resNoNA <- na.omit(res)
resNoNAS <- scale(resNoNA[, 3:6])
colMeans(resNoNA[, 3:6])
apply(resNoNA[, 3:6], 2, sd)
cluster2 <- kmeans(resNoNAS, centers = 2)
table(cluster2$cluster)
## this gives standardized answer, which is hard to interpret
cluster2$centers
## better to subset the original data and then compute means
g1 <- resNoNA[cluster2$cluster == 1, ]
colMeans(g1[, 3:6])
g2 <- resNoNA[cluster2$cluster == 2, ]
colMeans(g2[, 3:6])

plot(x = resNoNA$logGDPcp, y = resNoNA$illit, main = "Illiteracy v GDP",
xlab = "GDP per Capita",  ylab = "Illiteracy", 
col = cluster2$cluster, cex = resNoNA$oil)
```

but I wanted to make the circles smaller in order to fit within the limits of the graph

[image]

Comment: Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically after `set.seed(1)`), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. (With what you've provided ... who knows.)

Comment: Perhaps this one helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579995/control-the-size-of-points-in-an-r-scatterplot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You control the circle diameter with `cex=` here.

```r
plot(x = resNoNA$logGDPcp, y = resNoNA$illit, main = "Illiteracy v GDP",
xlab = "GDP per Capita",  ylab = "Illiteracy", 
col = cluster2$cluster, cex = resNoNA$oil)
plot(x = resNoNA$logGDPcp, y = resNoNA$illit, main = "Illiteracy v GDP",
xlab = "GDP per Capita",  ylab = "Illiteracy", 
col = cluster2$cluster, cex = resNoNA$oil/3)
plot(x = resNoNA$logGDPcp, y = resNoNA$illit, main = "Illiteracy v GDP",
xlab = "GDP per Capita",  ylab = "Illiteracy", 
col = cluster2$cluster, cex = resNoNA$oil/5)
```

[image: 3-pack of images]

Realize, however, that if you are using this in some automated report generator (e.g., `rmarkdown`, `shiny`), then you may need to adjust the dimensions of the plot to control it from the other angle: update `xlim` and `ylim`.